# Can't create a new user on Angular Sign Up page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, post

I am trying to create a new user in Angular. I'm attempting to send a POST request to my api through the client side to create a new user. Unfortunately I can't successfully send the post request. Sending the request through Postman is successful, but not through Angular. Any ideas on what could be the issue? Any help is appreciated.

**userCtrl.js**

```
//./public/app/controllers/userCtrl.js

angular.module('userCtrl',['userService'])

  //SIGN UP CTRL ================================
  //inject the User factory
  .controller('userCreateController', function($location, User){
    var vm = this;

    //Function that creates a new user
    vm.saveUser = function(){
      //For spinner animation when signing up
      vm.processing = true;

      //Use the create funciton in the userService
      User.create(vm.userData)
        .then(function(data){
          if(data.success){
            $location.path('/login');
          }else {
            console.log('error');
            vm.processing = false;
          }
        })
    }//End saveUser

  })//End userCreateController
```

**userService.js**

```
//userService.js

angular.module('userService', [])

  .factory('User', function($http){
    //create a user factory object
    var userFactory = {};

    //get a single user
    userFactory.get = function(id){
      return $http.get('/api/users/' + id);
    };

    //get all users
    userFactory.all = function(){
      return $http.get('/api/users/');
    };

    //create a user
    userFactory.create = function(userData){
      return $http.post('/api/users/', userData);
    };

    //update a user
    userFactory.update = function(id, userData){
      return $http.put('/api/users/' + id, userData);
    };

    //delete a user
    userFactory.delete = function(id){
      return $http.delete('/api/users' + id);
    };

    //return userFactory object
    return userFactory;

  });
```

**routes.js**

```
//./public/app/routes.js

angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider

    //homepage route
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/home.html'
    })

    .when('/login',{
      templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/login.html',
      controller: 'mainController',
      controllerAs: 'login'
    })

    .when('/signup',{
      templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/signup.html',
      controller: 'userCreateController',
      controllerAs: 'signup'
    })

    //Remove hash in the Url
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  })//End config
```

**signup.html**

```
<div class="row col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
  <div class="jumbtron">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>

    <!-- Sign Up Form -->
    <form ng-submit='signup.saveUser()'>

      <!-- Name Input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" ng-model='signup.userData.name'>
      </div>

      <!-- Username Input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" ng-model='signup.userData.username'>
      </div>

      <!-- Password Input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model='signup.userData.password'>
      </div>


      <!-- Signup Button -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
        <!-- Show SignUP -->
        <span ng-if="!signup.processing">Sign Up</span>
        <!-- Show spinner animation when signing up -->
        <span ng-if="signup.processing" class="spinner">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
        </span>
      </button>

    </form>
    <!-- End Sign Up Form -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The post is not even issued or are you getting error back from the post?

Comment: @Gustav  The post is not sent at all. It's supposed to redirect the user to the login page, but when the input fields are filled and the user hits submit the page stays on the sign up page. On my server side I'm getting a 200 status on POST /api/users. But the user is not in my database.

Comment: you should know that $http will return a response object with a data property that is what you returned from your backend. So I guess `.success` is a property on your returned object you need to do `data.data.success`, because it does  not exist on $http response object

Comment: But also you should use the fact that it is a promise api, that if your backend rejects the request you should not return OK but with a boolean property `.success` set to false, but use the second parameter to the `.then`-function which is a error callback

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without more information like the browser console log, but if you are minifying the code, it could be due to the [implicit annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) syntax used in the controller injection.

Try to write it with the preferred **Inline Array Annotation** like:

```
.controller('userCreateController',
  ['$location', 'User', function($location, User){
      ...
}]);
```

Comment: I believe that [my other response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32672585/4928558) is more likely to guess the problem.

Answer (score 0):

at `signup.html` you are modifying `signup.userData.*` but at `userCtrl.js` you are sending `vm.userData` instead of `$scope.signup.userData`.

The problem could be that you are sending an undefined object instead of the userData object.

Comment: In my routes I'm declaring an alias for the userController as signup. That doesn't seem to be the issue because I just checked my database and it's actually giving me successful post. Don't know what the issue was  before but it's halfway working. Now it's not redirecting me to the login page for some reason...